# Java EE managed Container Collection operation not Propagating to DB

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many

I will confessed that I have got really confused lately and I need to take a step back and start the basics again for Java EE.

After reading some materials I got the believing that I can do some operations on my entities or collections and this will be translated by the Container or JPA to some sql.
I tried this and it worked as I expected

```
  public List<Manufacturer> addProductByContainerManaged(Integer manufacId, Product prod){
    Manufacturer manu = this.manufacturerDao.find(manufacId);
    manu.getProductList().add(prod);
    prod.setManufacturerId(manu);
    return this.manufacturerDao.findAll();
}
```

But this operation didnt add any item in the DB, so I guess I am missing something.

```
  public List<Manufacturer> addManufacturer(Manufacturer manufac){  
    List<Manufacturer> ret = this.manufacturerDao.findAll();
    ret.add(manufac);
   return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second snippet just adds the `Manufacturer manufac` object to the **java** `List` (see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html). Then your method returns this list. Calling `add(...)` on the `List` element does just that, adds an element to the list.

If you want to add it to the DB, you obviously have to call the `add(...)` method implemented by you (or whoever) on the `ManufacturerDAO` in order to save it in the DB (like in the first snippet).

If you want the second snippet to work, then you have to do something like:

```
public List<Manufacturer> addManufacturer(Manufacturer manufac){  
    this.manufacturerDao.save(manufac); //I am not sure about your api. It could be something like this.
    List<Manufacturer> ret = this.manufacturerDao.findAll();
    return ret;
}
```